# Power consumption for various colors in android

Tags: android

I wanted to measure the battery consumption of various colors in the range of 0-255 in android. Wanted  to do it through an application. Currently I am using the PowerManager to measure the initial level of Battery and then keeping the screen bright for say 10-20 mins and check the final battery level, the difference  giving me the usage in %. But I am getting weird results as in "white" uses same power as "black" (both having a drop of 4%). So I think my appraoch may be wrong. Can someone please suggest me to appraoch the problem in a correct way. Please help !!

Comment: If in 20 minutes the difference wasn't big enough to be seen you must wait longer time, let's say 200 minutes. Also, to have a good statistical base you should make the test more than once for each color so the random component will be dissociated. Try longer times and give us feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what device you are using, but usually what really consumes the battery is the backlight, while the color is disposable in terms of power consumption.

Comment: Hi Andre and Michael , I am using an OLED screen, so can you please suggest some way of doing what I jus wrote in my question?

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I co-founded the company that built the below product)

Try [Little Eye](http://www.littleeye.co) from Little Eye Labs, which lets you track an individual apps power consumption and breaks it down into its various hardware usage, including display, CPU and wifi (and shortly GPS). Based on the pixel color and the brightness levels used, the power consumption trend of the app will vary, and Little Eye helps you visualize that quite easily. Note its a desktop product (which connects to your phone) that you need to download and install from [here](http://www.littleeye.co)

Answer (score 0):

There's an official power estimation tool called [Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html).It will create a text file which will show the power consumption of each component of the device in mAh.

I also suggest you to run you App for a longer time like 1 hour because the power consumption difference may be very small.

I hope this will help you.