# Lower battery consumption Android

Tags: android, optimization, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optimizing Android application before release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626947/optimizing-android-application-before-release)

How can we lower battery consumption in Android?

I've searched a bit, and found :

- Using darker colors
- Using as little cyclic triggers as possible
- Lower network usage (count of connections, timeout of cache, etc..)
- Using less Broadcast receivers
- Distribute application load, when dock is connected
- Using [setInexactRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for periodic actions

anything else you would recommend to verify ?

[[1]](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770021/how-to-get-information-about-android-battery-usage-by-application) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937162/power-consumption-for-various-colors-in-android) [[4]](https://grepular.com/Android_Battery_Graphing_Source_Code) [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619133/hidden-features-of-android-development#answer-1665926) [[6]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Question and its Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626947/optimizing-android-application-before-release) should give you a pretty good idea of all that can be done - e.g less memory consumption will require less garbage collection and thus less cpu usage etc.

Comment: ah, I missed this question when searching. feel free to close as duplicate than.